# How can I interpret multiple alignment results?

Tags: sequence-alignment, proteins

I would like to ask how I can interpret objectively multiple alignment results. I have used JALVIEW  and TCOFFEE.

1. I would like to ask if consistency score plays any role in the interpretation?
2. I would like to ask for a region of a protein to be considered conserved, all the amino acids should have similar properties? So even if only one protein has a different amino acid (among the proteins that are included in the multiple alignment), then there is no conservation? for example, in this picture,
3. I am curious why there is no dot beneath some columns with almost identical amino acids (expect one sequence for example).[image]

Comment: Good question but we will need to know what the purpose of conservation analysis is. Make primers? State "region of conservation"? Design a vaccine?

Comment: the ultimate goal is to find some information about the structure and the function of an unknown protein sequence.

Comment: Thanks I'll respond in a few days, my apologies for the delay in advance.

Comment: no worries!thank you so much for your help!i am grateful!